# Does wild elf luck add to oath of enmity?

Tags: dnd-4e, avenger, elf

Does wild elf luck[<sup>ddi</sup>](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=633) (add a d4 when using elven accuracy) add to both d20's that an avenger re-rolls when re-rolling an attack using oath of enmity[<sup>ddi</sup>](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=3069)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, but...**
Oath of Enmity explicitly states that if an effect makes you reroll and 
you rolled twice because of of the Oath, you reroll both dice.

> **[Oath of Enmity](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/display.aspx?page=power&id=3069)**<sup>DDI</sup>
>   *[...]*
>   If an effect lets you reroll an attack roll and you rolled twice because of this power, you reroll both dice.

That's the case of Elven Accuracy.

> **[Elven Accuracy](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=1450)**<sup>DDI</sup>
>   *With an instant of focus, you take careful aim at your foe and strike with the legendary accuracy of the elves.*
>   **Encounter**
>   **Free Action - Personal**
>   **Trigger:** You make an attack roll and dislike the result.
>   **Effect:** Reroll the attack roll. Use the second roll, even if it’s lower.

Now, Wild Elf Luck allows to add a +1d4 to the reroll when you use Elven Accuracy.

> **[Wild Elf Luck](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=633)**<sup>DDI</sup>
>   **Heroic Tier**
>   **Prerequisite:** Elf
>   **Benefit:** When you use your elven accuracy power, you gain a +1d4 bonus to the reroll.
>   **Special:** You cannot select this feat if you have the Wood Elf Agility feat.

I see at least 4 ways of interpreting it.

1. You roll 1d4 and add the result to one d20 roll only `max(d20+d4, d20)`
2. You roll 1d4 and add the result to both your d20 rolls `x=d4, max(d20+x, d20+x)`
3. You roll 1d4 and add the result to the best of your d20 rolls `max(d20, d20)+d4`.
4. You roll 1d4 and add the result to the first d20 roll, then roll another 1d4 and add the result to the second d20 roll `max(d20+d4, d20+d4)`.

Option #2 and option #3 seem equivalent, but I'll opt for #3 because Oath of Enmity transforms the "reroll" into the best of two d20 rolls (`max(d20, d20)`), then Wild Elf Luck kicks in by adding 1d4 to the reroll result (`+d4`).

So, answering to your question, Wild Elf Luck behaves as applying to both rolls, even if it applies to the best of the two.
Difference between #2 and #3 could become important under other circumstances.